# Fetching comments on a Google Doc using Google Drive API: EmalAddress of the comment owner is returned null

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-docs

I have the following code to fetch comments on a given Google Doc. For the `Fields`, I provided the `*` value to retrieve all information. I can retrieve the `Author.DisplayName` value properly but `Author.EmailAddress` is always `null`. I wonder if this a normal behavour. How can I mitigate this?

```
public IList<Comment> RetrieveComments(string fileId)
{
    var _driveService = GetDriveServiceInstance();

    try
    {

        CommentsResource.ListRequest commentRequest = _driveService.Comments.List(fileId);
        commentRequest.Fields = "*";

        CommentList comments = commentRequest.Execute();

        return comments.Comments;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The field `EmailAddress` is not populated for [`Comments`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments#resource)

> author
>
> nested object
>
> The author of the comment. The author's email address and permission ID will not be populated.

Comment: But then why it is there?

Comment: It is there because you can use it to insert Comments.

Comment: Then there is no way to integrate Google Doc with a third party application? I have the gmail address of the users in the system, and I want to identify who provided comments by matching the gmail addresses, which seems impossible.

Comment: Correct, the only way would be to tie it with the displayName value.